# How to hack this URL with BurpSuite?

Tags: javascript, get, http-headers

The website shows a list of active users, nothing else. Goal is to edit the header to include some bash command injection to crack the site, and this will give a URL for the next site to try and break for a security testing course.

The URL has two GET requests one when the page is loading (1) and one when the website is 'checking for users' (2)

This is the GET request (2):

```
GET /ekohshahrabohpha/cgi-bin/users.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 134.219.148.11:61166
Connection: close
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4
Accept-Language: en-us
Referer: http://134.219.148.11:61166/ekohshahrabohpha/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

This is the Header (1):

```
GET /ekohshahrabohpha/ HTTP/1.1
Host 134.219.148.11:61166
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X ... )
Accept-Language en-us
Cache-Control max-age=0
Connection close
```

The source code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Level 2</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Level 2</h1>
      <p class="lead">
        <h2>Active Users</h2>
      </p>
    </div>


    <div id="userlist">
      <pre>Checking for users...</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
<script language="JavaScript">
var http_request = false;

  function getusers() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // non IE
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { //
      try {
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (error) {}
    }
    if (!http_request) {
      alert('Cannot create XML HTTP instance');
      return false;
    }

    http_request.onreadystatechange = stateManager;
    var myurl = "cgi-bin/users.php";
    var f = document.getElementById("filter");
    if (f != null) {
      if (f.value != '') {
        myurl = myurl + "?filter=" +  f.value;
      }
    }
    http_request.open("GET", myurl, true);
    http_request.send(null);
  }

  function stateManager() {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
      if (http_request.status == 200) {
        updatepage(http_request.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }

  function updatepage(str) {
    document.getElementById("userlist").innerHTML = str;
  }

  setTimeout("getusers()", 5000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding ?filter= after GET request (2) with bash commands but it hasn't done anything. Wondering what I could add to crack the page.

Comment: See [security.se]

Comment: I would try sql-injection on the `filter` query param. My memory about it is very vague though, i may be wrong.